# Web deploy backup fails "You cannot create or restore a backup of multiple databases in a single sync"

Tags: backup, webdeploy

I'm lost with this, especially after following the [guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups) on how to configure this.

This is how the webdeploy is configured in the iis host config:

```
<wdeploy>
    <backup turnedOn="true" enabled="true"
        numberOfBackups="4"
        backupPath="C:\inetpub\Backups\{siteName}"
        continueSyncOnBackupFailure="false">
        <excludedProviders>
            <provider name="dbMySql" />
            <provider name="dbFullSql" />
        </excludedProviders>
    </backup>
</wdeploy>
```

As per the documentation:

**What a Backup Contains** ([documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups))

"...You can change this default behavior by modifying the ExcludedProviders backup setting, or by specifying skip rules before doing a publish."

**Web Deploy providers** ([documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569040%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

"Web Deploy dbFullSql Provider" The dbFullSql provider enables first-time publishing of databases from a local SQL Server development database to a remotely hosted SQL Server database.

When I go to deploy I get the following message:

`Error: BACKUP_FAILED - Skipping backup because it failed due to an unknown reason. For more information, contact your server administrator.
Error: You cannot create or restore a backup of multiple databases in a single sync.
Error count: 1.`

My questions/issues are why is the backup attempting to backup more than one database and why would this be even attempting to backup the databases when the provider has been excluded in the config.

Help!

Comment: Behind the scenes it uses the iisApp provider. Perhaps if you try recreating the command line and running manually you could get more info about the failure.

Comment: Good idea, I'll give that a try. I'll be using a different server/environment which might shed some more light.

Comment: Still not joy with this. I thought it might have something to do with another connection string in web config but I've removed that and still getting the error :(

Comment: Did you check the web deploy logs in event viewer?

Comment: Not yet @MikeCheel but with my curiosity to get this working I will be soon.  TBH I wasn't sure where the logs for these routines would go, but [do now](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-common-problems-with-web-deploy).

Comment: What's even more disheartening about this is that the error "You cannot create or restore a backup of multiple databases in a single sync" only returns 2 results in google... and both of them point to this question :(

Comment: At least you aren't trying to use msdeploy.exe with powershell. In the end Ihaveto resort call it from batch files.

Comment: @MikeCheel The event viewer has revealed no more than the original error.

Comment: Manual execution of the backup using msdeploy works `.\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:backupManager -dest:backupManager=[siteName]`.  I'm might have to look into running this manually before deployment.

Comment: Just curious is this happening from tfs? There should be a detailed log of what is happening during web deploy. If not then try and use msbuild with detailed logging and that might shed some help. These are the things I would be trying.

Comment: And to be clear if you are using tfs there is a detailed text file log and if not you can use msbuild at the command line with various logging switches.